# Is there any way to mock and test Salesforce Streaming?

Tags: unit-test, streaming-api, mock

Is there any way to mock and test Salesforce Streaming?
How do you test Salesforce Streaming API ?

Comment: Be a bit more explicit here - what/who are the subscribers/consumers of the stream?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible.

```
 @isTest static void testPlatformEvent() {
        SomeEvent__e event = new SomeEvent__e(SomeField='test');

        Test.startTest();
        Database.SaveResult sr = EventBus.publish(event);
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(true, sr.isSuccess());
```

For more information read Salesforce [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_apex_tests.htm)

Comment: this testmethod, while correct, actually tests nothing of interest. By definition, `EventBus.publish(event)` will always work in the test context provided you are not publishing more than 500 events. Consumption of the event is what one would test in a testmethod and that requires the org to have a subscriber (trigger/PB/flow) that leaves some persistence behind to asset against